# c# IRR function (arguments not valid exception)

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with the c# IRR function I'm getting the "Arguments not valid" exception,I have an array of netcash for each year in a given project:

```
 public double IRR
{
    get
    {
          var operatingYears =
            EntProject.ResultYearSet.Where(p => p.YearType == YearTypeEnum.Operating)
                      .Select(x => (double)x.NetCash)
                      .ToArray();


        return NavitasFormulae.GetInternalRateofReturn(operatingYears);
    }
```

IRR function:

```
 public static double GetInternalRateofReturn(double[] values,double guess = 0.0001)
{
    try
    {
        return Financial.IRR(ref values);

    }

    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // throw new BusinessException(BusinessExceptionEnum.Operational,
        //                           "Cannot calculate IRR from the yearly values");

        return 0; //If the series of values are not suitable, then the function will return zero.

    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessExceptionEnum.Operational,
                                    "The IRR Function encountered an error");
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the guess to different values and have passed a negative number in the array also(the sum of the total cost for each year), but still no luck?

Comment: What does the `Financial.IRR(ref double[])` method look like?

Comment: It looks like you've got the concepts of methods and properties mixed up.  IRR is set up as a read-only property, since it has no Set routine only a Get.  Then you're trying to call it like a method.

Comment: @tinstaafl I actually do believe that `Financial.IRR` is a separate method, otherwise the whole thing would not even compile. Also, if the `IRR` property would be accessed in the `GetInternalRateOfReturn` method, this would result in an endless loop since the `IRR` property in turn accesses the `Get...` method. So I don't think the OP is mixing up methods and properties, although I do agree that the code is a little confusing.

Comment: Fininacial.IRR method:                                                                                                                                   public static double IRR(ref double[] ValueArray, double Guess = 0.1);

Comment: @tinstaafl, basically I have a class called ResultsConfiguration with a property called IRR when I get ResultsConfisguration.IRR the property calls the Fininacial.IRR method and returns the result of the values passed in by the IRR property

Comment: I guess the exception is thrown in the `Financial.IRR` method? Do you have access to this code? Also, consider passing `guess` in the `Financial.IRR` call, as it is right now the `guess` variable is unused.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have access to the method, and I just tried passing guess also,still throwing the exception.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `ref`?  Since values is a parameter wouldn't it be passed by reference automatically?  That would make passing it by reference to IRR passing a reference to a reference.

Comment: @tinstaafl, I am having the same issue and if I remove the ref it throws another error because ref is obligatory.

Comment: @nicolascolman - You should submit a new question and include the relevant code.  It's hard to diagnose the problem without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Hope is not too late. I was dealing with this issue and I changed the guess value for IRR method to 0.00000001.

The result of IRR will never be zero. So guess value indicates how near of zero IRR result will be.

```
rate = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.IRR(ref values, 0.00000001);
```

I'm calling this function from C#